# Pass current GNU screen window number to backtick command

Tags: gnu-screen

is there a way to send/pass the current window number to a backtick command in GNU screen? Or would I have to use a different terminal multiplexer?

Thank you.

Edit:

This is my backtick:

```
backtick 0 2 2 $HOME/bin/status/status
```

Inside my "hardstatus string" line the backtick is inserted:

```
hardstatus string "... %{=b dw}[ %{-b dc}%0`%{=b dw} ]"
```

Inside the status script (more precisely inside scripts run by `$HOME/bin/status/status`) I would like to know which window is currently shown.

Comment: Please elaborate. What would you like to do with the screen number?

Answer (score 3):

From the [environment section](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Environment.html#Environment) of the screen man page, the `WINDOW` environment variable contains "Window number of a window (at creation time)." Note that this will not be available if you `su -` within the window (or otherwise wipe out the environment of your user).

---

If you're trying to add a visual indicator of the current window by inserting the window number in the shell prompt, do you know that the status line at the bottom of the screen can show you this?

Here's the bit from my .screenrc file which configures this for me:

```
# An alternative hardstatus to display a bar at the bottom listing the
# window names and highlighting the current window name in blue. 
hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%{.bW}%-w%{.rW}%n %t%{-}%+w %=%{..G} %H %{..Y} %l %m/%d %c "
```

The [string escapes](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/String-Escapes.html#String-Escapes) section of the man page goes into more detail about what you can put into the status line.

Comment: Thanks for the environmnet hint. Unfortunately WINDOW is only set for the corresponding terminal, the backtick script has the original environment. Passing %n as an argument in the backtick definition line doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'd like to do something like this: if current-screen-windownumber is 1 then delete some log file.

Comment: Something about that strikes me as odd. I view `screen` as a mere presentation tool -- not tightly integrated with the functionality of the system. By deleting a log file based on which screen you're currently looking at, you're combining the two. If you're logging output of a command running within screen you could either redirect the output to a file (optionally using `tee` so that you could watch also) or you could use screen's `log` command to capture the output.

Comment: Thanks, nice one!